# Command Line RDP in windows 7/ server 2008 OR open source code

Tags: windows, console, remote-desktop

I was wondering if it possible to initiate a RDP session in windows that is purely on the command line, that is, login, passwords, directory traversal etc. If not, is there any open source project that allows so? I do not need the GUI version of RDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SSH for administration. That's what i usually do: Install Cygwin with a ssh service.

Comment: There are (or at least once were) security issues with Cygwin on multi-user machines.  Care may be needed.

Comment: One alternative is psexec (available from Microsoft).

Answer (score 0):

As Harry points out, you can run a remote command prompt using psexec:

```
psexec \\computername cmd.exe
```

A good psexec Tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/